# How to add calculated rows to a tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's my tibble.

```
 A tibble: 5 x 4
  Site     Pre  Post Pct_Change
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Site 1 0.244 0.254       4.1 
2 Site 2 0.209 0.211       0.96
3 Site 3 0.309 0.302      -2.27
4 Site 4 0.315 0.313      -0.63
5 Site 5 0.31  0.316       1.94
```

I would like to add four more rows that calculate the percent difference for each column variable (`Pre`, `Post`, `Pct_Change`) between `Site 1` and `Site 2`, `Site 1` and `Site 3`, `Site 1` and `Site 4` and `Site 1` and `Site 5`. I would like the row layout to look like this.

```
 A tibble: 5 x 4
      Site     Pre  Post Pct_Change
      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
    1 Site 1 0.244 0.254       4.1 
    2 Site 2 0.209 0.211       0.96
    3 Diff
    4 Site 3 0.315 0.313      -0.63
    5 Diff
    6 Site 4 0.244 0.254       4.1 
    7 Diff
    8 Site 5 0.309 0.302      -2.27
    9 Diff
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to do this with rows, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to perform calculation for each `Site` ? I mean what about `Site2` vs `Site3`, `Site2` vs `Site4` and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution, if I got your purpose right:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_split(Site) %>%
  map_dfr(~ add_row(.x, Site = "Diff", Pre = .x$Pre, Post = .x$Post, 
                    Pct_Change = df$Pct_Change[1] - .x$Pct_Change)) %>%
  filter(Pct_Change != 0)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Site     Pre  Post Pct_Change
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Site_1 0.244 0.254       4.1 
2 Site_2 0.209 0.211       0.96
3 Diff   0.209 0.211       3.14
4 Site_3 0.309 0.302      -2.27
5 Diff   0.309 0.302       6.37
6 Site_4 0.315 0.313      -0.63
7 Diff   0.315 0.313       4.73
8 Site_5 0.31  0.316       1.94
9 Diff   0.31  0.316       2.16
```

Here is just another way:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  summarise(Site = "Diff",
            Pre = Pre,
            Post = Post,
            Pct_Change = df$Pct_Change[1] - Pct_Change) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(Pre) %>%
  filter(Pct_Change != 0)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Site     Pre  Post Pct_Change
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Diff   0.209 0.211       3.14
2 Site_2 0.209 0.211       0.96
3 Site_1 0.244 0.254       4.1 
4 Diff   0.309 0.302       6.37
5 Site_3 0.309 0.302      -2.27
6 Diff   0.31  0.316       2.16
7 Site_5 0.31  0.316       1.94
8 Diff   0.315 0.313       4.73
9 Site_4 0.315 0.313      -0.63
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'Diff' rows would move away from [tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) principles that {tidyverse} tools are designed for. Instead,  I added new columns to obtain the results you needed.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(pre_diff = .$Pre[1] - Pre,
         post_diff = .$Post[1] - Post)

# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   Site     Pre  Post Pct_Change pre_diff post_diff
#   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 Site 1 0.244 0.254       4.1     0         0    
# 2 Site 2 0.209 0.211       0.96    0.035     0.043
# 3 Site 3 0.309 0.302      -2.27   -0.065    -0.048
# 4 Site 4 0.315 0.313      -0.63   -0.071    -0.059
# 5 Site 5 0.31  0.316       1.94   -0.066    -0.062
```